# Could not download image from url link using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver, python-imaging-library

I would like to download an image from the web, but I always get an error regardless of the method used. However, I have no problems to download other images using this method.

works - https://mobec.sk/proxy/geo?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=global%3Abase&tiled=true&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A180&BBOX=1934774.0599543825%2C6239707.492975509%2C1937220.044859508%2C6242153.477880634

does not work - https://mobec.sk/proxy/geo?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=custom%3Avrbovce_elektrina&tiled=true&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A180&BBOX=1947003.9844800085%2C6242153.477880634%2C1949449.969385134%2C6244599.46278576

**Method 1**

Using the Python's requests and Pillow libraries. Here the image should be downloaded directly from the url.

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://mobec.sk/proxy/geo?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=custom%3Avrbovce_elektrina&tiled=true&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A180&BBOX=1947003.9844800085%2C6242153.477880634%2C1949449.969385134%2C6244599.46278576'

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))   # error occurs here
img.save('output.png')
```

I get the following error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x04956510>
```

**Method 2**

Using the Python's Selenium library and chromedriver. Here I am trying to show the image in web browser and printscreen the whole page using the Selenium library.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://mobec.sk/proxy/geo?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=custom%3Avrbovce_elektrina&tiled=true&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A180&BBOX=1947003.9844800085%2C6242153.477880634%2C1949449.969385134%2C6244599.46278576'

chrome = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
chrome.get(url)

png = chrome.get_screenshot_as_png()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
im.save('output.png')

chrome.quit()
```

The problem with this method is that the image is not loaded (shown) in the Chrome browser opened by the chromedriver driver. When manually pasting the link into a normal (desktop app) Chrome the image is shown.

[image: Method 2 - image does not load into chrome]

Answer (score 1):

I tested both methods on both links and it looks like there's something wrong with the second link: first one works perfectly fine, either while manually opening it with a browser or using any of those methods; the second one doesn't open in a browser and gives an error in both methods (that are both fine code-wise).

As written in the error message -  `Could not find layer custom:vrbovce_elektrina` - in both methods and manual pasting the browser can't find a layer called `vrbovce_elektrina`. Maybe there's a typo there or there is no such image/layer on this page.

The code is good, it's just that the link doesn't work.

Comment: That is what I thought. When I click on the second link the browser will try to open the image but give me the error (Fig. 1). However, when I copy the link and paste it as an url into a new web browser tab the image is shown. Do you have any idea why is it so?

Comment: No idea to be honest, because I can't open the second link at all. Tried using different browsers, tried using different drivers in selenium (chrome, phantomjs etc.) and I still can't see the image.

Comment: I was thinking if the problem is not in the information passed to the web server in the header of the HTTP request (language, user, ...). I have tried to change the header so it will not obtain information that the request was sent by a python script. Nevertheless, I don't know why you are not able to open it (Could it be opened only in my country? Why only this specific layer?)

Comment: yeah, i know it's weird. would be helpful to see if anyone else can open the link

Comment: Finally, I have managed to download this and other similar images. I don't know why, but it worked when I opened the following url first (method 2): "https://mobec.sk/vrbovce#base" (this is the website which shows a map from these images).

Comment: glad it worked. funnily, opening it the way you suggested now works also for me :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Piotrek wrote the problem was not in the code. I guess that the problem was on the server side. This is what worked for me:

1. I have used **Method 2**
2. before opening the url link I have opened the following "parent" url
   (https://mobec.sk/vrbovce#base), which uses these images to
       create a map
3. in the next step, I have opened the url link of the image in the
   chrome web browser using the selenium python module
4. afterwards, I could take a screenshot of the image

This is the code that worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

web_driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
web_driver.get('https://mobec.sk/vrbovce#base')

web_driver.get('https://mobec.sk/proxy/geo?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=custom%3Avrbovce_elektrina&tiled=true&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A180&BBOX=1947003.9844800085%2C6242153.477880634%2C1949449.969385134%2C6244599.46278576')

png = web_driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
im.save('output.png')

web_driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using requests, just write the response content to a file:

```
with open('image-file', 'wb') as fp: 
   fp.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) library for that.

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

url = 'https://mobec.sk/proxy/geo?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=global%3Abase&tiled=true&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A180&BBOX=1934774.0599543825%2C6239707.492975509%2C1937220.044859508%2C6242153.477880634'

response = requests.request("GET", url)
image = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))
image.save('output.png')
```

for python3;

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://mobec.sk/proxy/geo?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=global%3Abase&tiled=true&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A180&BBOX=1934774.0599543825%2C6239707.492975509%2C1937220.044859508%2C6242153.477880634'

response = requests.request("GET", url)
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
image.save('output.png')
```

Comment: "from StringIO import StringIO" works only in Python 2. In Python 3 use "from io import StringIO". However, it does not work either and gives this error message: "TypeError initial_value must be str or None, not bytes".

Comment: I updated my answer for python3 and tried updated code at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GleefulGracefulBlock) and works fine.

Comment: The problem is that the code does not work with the url listed in the example. It worked well with the url you have used from the beginning. Try it with the "does not work" link and it will not run. Please see the first 2 links in the question. Anyway, thank you for the example you provided.